# Is it possible to mix use of LaTeX3 programing and amsmath environments like align?

Tags: align, latex3

Suppose I want to use the loop feature of LaTeX 3 to print some sequences of formulas in amsmath environments like align. How to do it?

Here is one failed example:

```
\seq_clear_new:N \l__example_seq
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__example_seq {a,b,c,d,e}
\begin{align*}
\int_until_do:nn {\seq_count:N \l__example_seq = 0}
{\seq_pop_left:NNTF \l__example_seq \l_tempa_tl 
{\tl_use:N \l_tempa_tl {&} \tl_use:N \l_tempa_tl {^{\tl_use:N \l_tempa_tl}}\\}
{} }
\end{align*}
```

The trouble is mainly due to the `&` in `align*` enviroment. **How to solve this issue**?
(P.S. I'm **not** asking how to apply functions to items in a list and looking for answers like \seq_map_inline. The above code is just to show the issue. )

Comment: Does the answer to the following post solve this as well? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/675021/264024 isn't it kind of a duplicate question? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Playing around a bit with your example to see what was happening, I rewrote it as:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_clear_new:N \l__example_seq
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__example_seq {a,b,c,d,e}
\begin{align*} % ❶
\int_until_do:nn 
   {\seq_count:N \l__example_seq = 0}
   {
     \seq_pop_left:NNTF 
        \l__example_seq 
        \l_tempa_tl 
        {
        \typeout{\l_tempa_tl} % ❷
        \tl_use:N \l_tempa_tl \& \tl_use:N \l_tempa_tl HAT{\tl_use:N \l_tempa_tl}\\ }
        {} 
   }
\end{align*} % ❶

\end{document}
```

to try to localize the error. Commenting out the `align*` environment on the lines marked ❶ (which is why I replaced `&` with `\&` and `^` with `HAT` (and also removed the incorrect braces around both the tab and the superscript expression), I got the expected results of the expansion, but when I put the `align*` back in place, it showed that the `\typeout` ❷ was giving `a` in an infinite loop. This was telling me that `\seq_pop_left` gets undone when the group ends with each row of the table (`\seq_gpop_left` should do the job).

The whole construction there seems a bit suspect to me. If you have a sequence, it makes much more sense to use `\seq_map_inline` or `\seq_map_function` to iterate through it than to do what you’re doing. You’ll find the following works and is less obtuse in its syntax:

```
\begin{align*}
\seq_map_inline:Nn 
  \l__example_seq
  {
    #1 & #1^{#1} \\
  }
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Thanks! What I'm wondering is why the alignment & breaks the code. As for the construction, it was supposed to be a loop relying on some operation on the sequence rather than just popping each item from it.