# Trouble with alignment and LaTeX3 recursion

Tags: align, latex3

Suppose we have 3 variables `\l__ta_seq`, `\l__tb_seq`, and `\l__tc_seq` in some LaTeX3 recursive process and we want to ship their contents:

```
        \seq_set_eq:NN \l__ta_seq \l__tb_seq
        \seq_set_eq:NN \l__tb_seq \l__tc_seq
```

However, if I try to do this inside an `align*` environment, things get messed up. Here is an example

```
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__ta_seq {1,2,3}
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__tb_seq {a,b,c}
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__tb_seq {x,y}
  \begin{align*}
    A&=\seq_use:Nn \l__ta_seq {+}\\
    B&=\seq_use:Nn \l__tb_seq {+}\\
    C&=\seq_use:Nn \l__tc_seq {+}\\
    \seq_set_eq:NN \l__ta_seq \l__tb_seq
    \seq_set_eq:NN \l__tb_seq \l__tc_seq
    A&=\seq_use:Nn \l__ta_seq {+}\\
    B&=\seq_use:Nn \l__tb_seq {+}\\
    C&=\seq_use:Nn \l__tc_seq {+}\\
  \end{align*}
```

You can find that the interchange doesn't happen.

**What cause this and how to solve it?**

**Update:** The goal is to put a recursion inside an `align*` environment.
Here is a (not) working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__ta_seq {1,2,3}
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__tb_seq {9,8,7}
  \seq_clear_new:N \l__tc_seq 

\usepackage{amsmath}
  \cs_new_nopar:Npn \fun_trim:N #1 {
    \bool_do_while:nn {
      \int_compare_p:n {\seq_count:N #1 > 1}
      &&
      \int_compare_p:n {\seq_item:Nn #1 {1} == 0}
    } {
      \seq_pop_left:NN #1 \l_tmpa_tl
    }
  }
  \cs_new_nopar:Npn \fun_seq:NNN #1#2#3
  {
    \seq_clear_new:N #1
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {1} {1} {\int_min:nn {\seq_count:N #2} {\seq_count:N #3}} {
      \seq_put_left:Nx #1 {\int_eval:n {\seq_item:Nn #2 {1} / \seq_item:Nn #3 {1} + 0}}
    }
    \fun_trim:N #1
  }
  %Some function produce \l__tc_seq from \l__ta_seq and \l__tb_seq, 

\begin{document}

  \begin{align*}
      A&=\seq_use:Nn \l__ta_seq {+}\\
      B&=\seq_use:Nn \l__tb_seq {+}\\
      C&=\seq_use:Nn \l__tc_seq {+}\\%Before the process
    \int_until_do:nn {
        \seq_count:N \l__tb_seq <= 1%Yes, I need it to be one or zero.
    }
    {
        \fun_seq:NNN \l__tc_seq \l__ta_seq \l__tb_seq
        \seq_set_eq:NN \l__ta_seq \l__tb_seq
        \seq_set_eq:NN \l__tb_seq \l__tc_seq
        A&=\seq_use:Nn \l__ta_seq {+}\\
        B&=\seq_use:Nn \l__tb_seq {+}\\
        C&=\seq_use:Nn \l__tc_seq {+}\\
    }
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

You can see that the issue is I need the variables being local so I can do the recursion.

**Update 2** Apologize for adding off-topic update. I realize that there is still an issue in the problem I meet. I know now that I need to store the result inside a token list. But in the actual situation I meet, I need to apply a complicated function to the sequence `\l__ta_seq` rather than use it directly. Here is a M(no)WE:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__ta_seq {1,2,3}
  \cs_new_nopar:Npn \fun_something:N #1 {
    \seq_map_inline:Nn #1 {##1} 
  }%In the actual situation, this should be a complicated function generating some math symbols (saying, a polynomial) from the sequence #1

  \tl_clear:N \l_results_tl
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_results_tl {\fun_something:N \l__ta_seq}
  %Let's ignore the recursion to make things simple.
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

So the issue is, the above code will cause errors `Use of \??? doesn't match its definition.` and `! LaTeX Error: A sequence was misused.` But I have no idea what's wrong.

By the way, although modifying the function `\fun_something:N` may be a reasonable solution, but the actual function is too complicated and I want to avoid modifying it.

Comment: Alignment cells form groups; you need global assignments (and global variables).

Comment: @egreg Thanks! But I need to use this construction in a recursion and hence the variables cannot be global. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: Do the manipulation outside of the align* environment and save the result inside a token list. Then use that token list inside the align environment

Comment: We need a M(not)WE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not fully clear, as you you don't explicitly say your final goal. Does this solve your problem?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__ta_seq {1,2,3}
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__tb_seq {a,b,c}
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__tc_seq {x,y} % you had a typo here...
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tempa_tl { \begin{align*} }
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tempa_tl
      {
        A&=\seq_use:Nn \l__ta_seq {+}\\
        B&=\seq_use:Nn \l__tb_seq {+}\\
        C&=\seq_use:Nn \l__tc_seq {+}\\
      }
    \seq_set_eq:NN \l__ta_seq \l__tb_seq
    \seq_set_eq:NN \l__tb_seq \l__tc_seq
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tempa_tl
    {
        A&=\seq_use:Nn \l__ta_seq {+}\\
        B&=\seq_use:Nn \l__tb_seq {+}\\
        C&=\seq_use:Nn \l__tc_seq {+}\\
      }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tempa_tl { \end{align*} }
    
        \l_tempa_tl
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This does solve my problem! By putting everything into a token list, the grouping caused by alignment `&` is avoided.

Comment: Actually, this still does not solve my goal, although it does work for the exam in question. May I ask in addition how to solve the following issue? If instead of `\seq_use:Nn \l__ta_seq {+}` (which works well), I use some function `\fun_bla:N \l__ta_seq`, it seems this will cause errors. Here the function \fun_bla:N` eats the sequence `\l__ta_seq` and prints something based on the information given by `\l__ta_seq` (a vector, or a polynomial, for example).

Comment: @Gau-Syu, that update deserve a new question. I can say in short that `\seq_map_inline:Nn` is a protected thus no expanding with the `x` argument specifier. Please as a new question with a *full* description of the problem. If you don't mind to post your complicated function and the whole code related to it, it would be the best way to solve your problem.